# python subtraction with list, without the first one

Tags: python, list, dataframe, arraylist, subtraction

I want to subtract these 2 list. But, without the first one (without 0,1621 and 0)
what should I do?

```
part1 = [0.16217332 0.31666873 0.51007364 0.66299792 0.83379235 1.        ]
part2 = [0.         0.26212295 0.42225925 0.61941848 0.81022938 1.        ]
```

I want the subtract `[(0.31666873-0.26212295) (0.51007364-0.42225925) (0.66299792-0.61941848) (0.83379235-0.81022938) (1-1)]`
with Python

Comment: have you tried *anything at all?* What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Are you using pandas.DataFrame? Your post is tagged with dataframe, but not Pandas.

Comment: Use list comprehension with zip & enumeration.

Comment: You can also turn the lists into numpy arrays and subtract them that way

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this, for example:

```
part1 = [0.16217332, 0.31666873, 0.51007364, 0.66299792, 0.83379235, 1.0  ]
part2 = [0.0,         0.26212295, 0.42225925, 0.61941848, 0.81022938, 1.0]

r = [part1[i] - part2[i] for i in range(1,len(part1)) ]

print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with numpy that allows vectorized subtraction of two arrays:

```
part1 = [0.16217332, 0.31666873, 0.51007364, 0.66299792, 0.83379235, 1.0  ]
part2 = [0.0,         0.26212295, 0.42225925, 0.61941848, 0.81022938, 1.0]

p1 = np.asarray(part1[1:])
p2 = np.asarray(part2[1:])
result = list(p1-p2)

#[0.05454577999999999, 0.08781439000000002, 0.043579440000000025, 0.02356296999999996, 0.0]
```